# Want replacement shifter hoods - how do I find the model of my shifters?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, shifter, compatibility, replacement

I'm looking for replacement shifter hoods for my bike - the current ones are original, and the bike's 13 years old.

I know my bike's a 2010 Specialized Roubaix Expert.  I've got the serial number.
It's Ultegra components all around, but components have gone through a couple transitions since 2010.

Do I need to figure out something like a model year for the shifters if I want replacement hoods that fit really well?  (If so, how?  Specialized's website doesn't easily tell me components on a 2010 bike)  Or are hoods fairly interchangeable and I'm worrying too much?

(Ironically, I could find a Specialized webpage describing the *2009* Roubaix Expert - so close!:  https://www.specialized.com/us/en/roubaix-expert/p/22412?color=31379-22412)

Comment: Aside - did the old hood rubber wear through from usage, or take damage from cleaners?   If the latter, keep the old damaged rubber to test cleaners on and see if it causes an adverse reaction.

Answer (score 4):

If your shifters have the shift cables exposed and running across the front of the bike, as in the model you linked, then you have Ultegra 6600 shifters. If the shift cables are completely concealed under the bar tape, you have 6700. Those are both 10-speed groups.

You can ask a bike store to tell you which model you have and to order you a pair of appropriate hoods. However, *how* do they tell? Basically, they’ll use familiarity with Shimano’s lineup. Since the 10-speed era, we typically get two generations of groups per speed, I.e. there are two generations of 10s and two generations of 11s groups. You can visually tell each generation apart. Basically, a lot of mechanics or cyclists would be able to identify by sight and memory, as I did in the first paragraph.

Also, the crankarms should have the group model number printed on them. On the R8000 Ultegra group, which is the second generation 11s group, the model is printed inside the arm by the hole for the pedals. I don’t know where else the model number is printed, but there may be a few more places. This might not help if you upgraded some things apart from the crank, or if the manufacturer specced a third party crank.

Last, a lot of bike pages on the web should list the component group and many of the components. Of course, these pages may be taken down. I think some bike manufacturers maintain historical pages, but this isn’t guaranteed. Newer cyclists could consider taking a PDF of the page when they buy their bike.

Be glad you aren’t asking about Campagnolo. [They don’t have model numbers, only internal and inscrutable part numbers](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/57169/does-campagnolo-have-a-groupset-model-number-system/87706#87706). Also, many bike stores may not be able to identify the parts due to lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

There's a possibility your bike is original spec espeically if you're the only owner. Things wear and get replaced so it pays to check the actual part number.   Once you have the `ST-XXXX` then that helps decide if a part will fit.

Shimano is good about putting a part number on their products.  Only downside is it can be hard to find.

The usual spot for an STI lever is on the body, under the rubber skirt:
[image]

For a brifter it might be on the side of the down-shift lever:
[image]

And for completeness, on a brake-only lever it may be on the side of the moving brake lever itself:

[image]
(not applicable to OP)

All images are from https://www.cyclemaintenanceacademy.com/shimano-components/shimano-parts/